# Replacing all mesh elements in a Mesh object

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

I'm working on the [Animation Nodes](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?350296-Addon-Animation-Nodes) Addon and want to create some new nodes which can work with mesh data like polygons. To output the created mesh I have to put it onto an object like this:

```
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name = "mesh")
mesh.from_pydata(vert_data, edge_data, face_data)
object.data = mesh
```

This works all fine but the problem is that this generates a new mesh object on each call, which means about 30 times per second.

I also tried to call `.from_data` on an existing Mesh but this just appends the new mesh data. Is there a clean and fast way to remove all verts, so that I can append the new data to an empty Mesh?

```
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.to_mesh(object.data)
object.data.from_pydata(vert_data, edge_data, face_data)
```

This seams to work but throws an error I don't understand (or more a warning).
This warning looks like here: https://developer.blender.org/T40571

Can someone explain this message or tell me a way to work around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions for the removal of mesh elements for [Mesh(ID)](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=mesh#bpy.types.Mesh.vertices) are [turned off in the source code](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_mesh.c#l2604).

```
#if 0 /* BMESH_TODO Remove until BMesh merge */
    func = RNA_def_function(srna, "remove", "ED_mesh_vertices_remove");
    RNA_def_function_flag(func, FUNC_USE_REPORTS);
    RNA_def_int(func, "count", 0, 0, INT_MAX, "Count", "Number of vertices to remove", 0, INT_MAX);
#endif
}
```

[`from_pydata`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/release/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py#l381) is a utility function written in python. You could use [bmesh](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bmesh.html#module-bmesh) but it might be slower.

I.e. (see [verts.new](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMVertSeq.new), [edges.new](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMEdgeSeq.new), [faces.new](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMFaceSeq.new))

```
import bmesh
bm = bmesh.new()
for co in vert_data:
    bm.verts.new(co)

#bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()    

for edge_indices in edge_data:
    bm.edges.new((
        bm.verts[edge_indices[0]],
        bm.verts[edge_indices[1]]
        ))
for face_indices in face_data:
    bm.faces.new(tuple(
        bm.verts[index] for index in face_indices
        ))

bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
bm.free()
```

Btw: I was able to crash blender using [this simple script](http://www.pasteall.org/55878/python) to test `from_pydata` for existing geometry.

Comment: ok thanks,
is there a similiar bmesh function for `from_pydata`?

Comment: I am not aware of any function resembling `from_pydata` for bmesh.

Comment: then I have to write this myself... :/ 
this will be quite slow

Comment: added a short section.

Comment: i see, 
I will try this out now. Thanks a lot

Comment: since Blender 2.73 you will have to run ``ensure_lookup_table``
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73/Addons

Comment: Ah, yes. I am not up to date.

Comment: you made this possible: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaWiZKNIXM4&feature=youtu.be
thanks :)